# Why not able to scrape all pages from a website with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get all the data from all pages,
i used a counter and cast it to take the page number in the url
then looped using this counter but always the same result
This is my code :

```
    # Scrapping job offers from hello work website

#import libraries
import random
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date

#configure user agent for mozilla browser

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0"
        ]

random_user_agent= random.choice(user_agents)
headers = {'User-Agent': random_user_agent}
```

here where i have used my counter:

```
i=0
    for i in range(1,15):  
        url = 'https://www.hellowork.com/fr-fr/emploi/recherche.html?p='+str(i)
        print(url)
        page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        if (page.status_code==200):
         soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
         jobs = soup.findAll('div',class_=' new action crushed hoverable !tw-p-4 md:!tw-p-6 !tw-rounded-2xl')
    
              #config csv
    
         csvfile=open('jobList.csv','w+',newline='')
         row_list=[] #to append list of job 
    
         try :
                writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow(["ID","Job Title","Company Name","Contract type","Location","Publish time","Extract Date"])
                for job in jobs:
                  id = job.get('id')
                  jobtitle= job.find('h3',class_='!tw-mb-0').a.get_text()
                  companyname = job.find('span',class_='tw-mr-2').get_text()
                  contracttype = job.find('span',class_='tw-w-max').get_text()
                  location = job.find('span',class_='tw-text-ellipsis tw-whitespace-nowrap tw-block tw-overflow-hidden 2xsOld:tw-max-w-[20ch]').get_text()
                  publishtime = job.find('span',class_='md:tw-mt-0 tw-text-xsOld').get_text()
                  extractdate = date.today()

              row_list=[[id,jobtitle,companyname,contracttype,location,publishtime,extractdate]]
              writer.writerows(row_list)
     finally:
            csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

`BeautifulSoup` is not necessary needed here - You could get all and more information directly via api using a mix of `requests` and [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) - Check all available information here:

```
https://www.hellowork.com/searchoffers/getsearchfacets?p=1
```

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
   
df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.json_normalize(
            requests.get(f'https://www.hellowork.com/searchoffers/getsearchfacets?p={i}', headers={'user-agent':'bond'}).json(), record_path=['Results']
        )[['ContractType','Localisation', 'OfferTitle', 'PublishDate', 'CompanyName']]

        for i in range(1,15)
    ],
    ignore_index=True
)

df['extractdate '] = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df.to_csv('jobList.csv', index=False)
```

##### Output

|  | ContractType | Localisation | OfferTitle | PublishDate | CompanyName | extractdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CDI | Beaurepaire - 85 | Chef Gérant H/F | 2023-01-24T16:35:15.867 | Armonys Restauration - Morbihan | 2023-01-24 |
| 1 | CDI | Saumur - 49 | Dessinateur Métallerie Débutant H/F | 2023-01-24T16:35:14.677 | G2RH | 2023-01-24 |
| 2 | Franchise | Villenave-d'Ornon - 33 | Courtier en Travaux de l'Habitat pour Particuliers et Professionnels H/F | 2023-01-24T16:35:13.707 | Elysée Concept | 2023-01-24 |
| 3 | Franchise | Montpellier - 34 | Courtier en Travaux de l'Habitat pour Particuliers et Professionnels H/F | 2023-01-24T16:35:12.61 | Elysée Concept | 2023-01-24 |
| 4 | CDD | Monaco | Spécialiste Senior Développement Matières Premières Cosmétique H/F | 2023-01-24T16:35:06.64 | Expectra Monaco | 2023-01-24 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 275 | CDI | Brétigny-sur-Orge - 91 | Magasinier - Cariste H/F | 2023-01-24T16:20:16.377 | DELPHARM | 2023-01-24 |
| 276 | CDI | Lille - 59 | Technicien Helpdesk Français - Italien H/F | 2023-01-24T16:20:16.01 | Akkodis | 2023-01-24 |
| 277 | CDI | Tours - 37 | Conducteur PL H/F | 2023-01-24T16:20:15.197 | Groupe Berto | 2023-01-24 |
| 278 | Franchise | Nogent-le-Rotrou - 28 | Courtier en Travaux de l'Habitat pour Particuliers et Professionnels H/F | 2023-01-24T16:20:12.29 | Elysée Concept | 2023-01-24 |
| 279 | CDI | Cholet - 49 | Ingénieur Assurance Qualité H/F | 2023-01-24T16:20:10.837 | Akkodis | 2023-01-24 |